# Do something in background

Tags: objective-c

I have some framework of mine which is do something that takes time,  and when i am trying to call a method of it , it actually freeze for 0.5 sec the movement in the screen .

i was trying to call it in background with :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(transmitNow:) withObject:nil];

-(void)transmitNow:(id)sender
{
     [instance sendWithData:data]; //takes time 

}
```

but it still takes the same amount of time .
is there a way to start this in the background so it will not stop the main process ?

Thanks .

Comment: Maybe show us more of the surrounding code, what you have there should quietly do the transmit in the background. The problem perhaps lies in the 'sendWithData' code.

Comment: Use grand central dispatch? There's a great tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTU4KaWVjuM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use and NSOperationQueue and NSOperation to do this. Consider the following code:

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:
^{
     [instance sendWithData:data];
}];
```

This will create an NSOperationQueue which is essentially a background thread. It will add an operation to that queue which will complete and then the thread will be automatically closed and cleaned up.

Read up on NSOperations and NSOperationQueue for more information.

Comment: thanks but the same..still take some time ..maybe i can say a little bit faster from the other answer ,but too much .

Comment: This code will perform the operation in a background thread, so there must be something else about the sendWithData function which is holding up the main thread. Can we see the contents of sendWithData?

Comment: OH its big...too big even to start. but i will check things my self and see when it do work with your code .

Answer (score 1):

I'd use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [instance sendWithData:data]; 
};
```

Comment: Sending it to the main thread would do pretty much the same as `performSelectorInBackground:`. Surely you'd want to send it to one of the other system queues?

Comment: Scheduling job to the main queue will still consume time of main (UI) thread and will not solve freezing problem at all. To do job in background, it must use something like `dispatch_get_global_queue()`.

Answer (score 0):

what you seem to have written should do what you want , I would put a breakpoint in make sure that is happening,
 also by calling this on a single threaded app, you will be switching to multi-threaded mode, which could account for the time you are seeing. calling again may be very fast.

doing things in the background can also be dangerous so be prepared to do some locking:

```
-(void)transmitNow:(id)sender
{
    @synchronized(data)
    {
         [instance sendWithData:data]; //takes time 
    }
}
```

also know that if you main thread runs into contention on data, it may still hang... just an fyi.

Comment: actually this app do have a few threads , and the function i call is having its own thread .